# Renaming index.ts as something else

Tags: typescript

This might be a redundant question, but I'm curious. Does typescript have other module resolution names instead of 'index.ts' in a directory? I mean usually, I include a index.ts in a directory(A) and simple import modules in it by referencing './A'.

So here comes a tiny discomfort. The editor alphabetically organizes the files and this index.ts in between is really awkward, it messes up my naming conventions. Is there anyway we can have an '_' or any other character in the front to push it to top of the list, just like we have it for python modules?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway we can have an '_' or any other character in the front to push it to top of the list, just like we have it for python modules?

You *could* with `tsconfig.json` path mapping, BUT Don't do that as `index.js` is *standard* for NodeJS. So just bite the bullet and learn to deal with it, instead of creating an abstraction specific to your project that people will have to learn.

Comment: You may still want this for an isomorphic approach, with `index.server.js` and `index.client.js` for instance.